# Error in loading SWF Animation in Android

Tags: android, webview, flash

No doubt this question was answered many times over the stackover flow and on many other sites. I have tried the all possible solutions but my problem is still there. Kindly can you please figure out the problem and how I fix it

I want to load SWF file that contain animation in android activity. But problem it this. It didn't show any output

**Look at this image**

[image]

**This is my code**

```
WebView mWebView;
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

String html = "<object width=\"200\" height=\"200\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///android_res/raw/ttl_logo_animate.swf\"> <embed src=\"file:///android_res/raw/ttl_logo_animate.swf\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\"> </embed> </object>";
String mimeType = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON); 
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

Any one can figure out the problem..?

**SDK Versions**

android:minSdkVersion="11"

android:targetSdkVersion="12"